# GUD debugger says: Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec"

Tags: gud, gdb

I am following the tutorial [Open GDB (within Emacs for added functionality)](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsy) on Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy
(the commands gud-gdb and gdb get the same results):

```
SPC f f (counsel-find-file) Find file: tutorial/foo.c
SPC c C (compile) Compile command: gcc -g -o foo foo.c
SPC SPC M-x gud-gdb foo (match required)
SPC SPC M-x gud-gdb
Run gud-gdb (like this): gud-gdb foo
```

Here are the screen shots:
[image]
[image]

What does "like this" mean?

It opens GUD interaction buffer `*gud-avg*`.
`avg` is the name of a previous program I was trying to debug.

Update: the GUD interaction buffer now opens to `*gud-foo*`.

Here are the screen shot:
[image]

Any how, the GUD interaction buffer did open, but it's broken:

```
(gdb) list
Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec".  Try "help".
(gdb) help
Undefined command: "-interpreter-exec".  Try "help".
```

Comment: At https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsy they use `M-x gdb` and not `M-x gud-gdb`. Note, that the grand unified debugger is [not that grand](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DebuggingWithEmacs#toc3). You could also try [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud).

Comment: M-x gud-gdb and M-x gdb get the same results.
I was using GUD because it came with Spacemacs and is described in the Emacs manual.
I will try realgud.

Comment: realgud worked on the first try.  That was easy.  Thanks Tobias!

Comment: I am always using `gdb`. For `gdb` the source of the error is pretty clear if you only use the command line `gdb foo`. You are missing the command line argument `-i=mi`. That argument says that `gdb` should provide the [line based machine oriented text interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html). It is unclear however why the emacs-command `gdb` does not include that command line argument in its default input. Did you edit the command line? The command line should read `gdb -i=mi foo` instead of `gdb foo`.

Comment: Thanks Tobias.  "Run gdb (like this): gdb -i=mi foo" worked.
I may have edited the command line the first time I tried the debugger, to match the command line shown in the tutorial.
The Emacs manual and GDB tutorial don't mention anything like GDB/MI or RealGUD.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Debuggers.html#Debuggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file and compile:

```
SPC f f (counsel-find-file) Find file: tutorial/foo.c
SPC c C (compile) Compile command: gcc -g -o foo foo.c
```

There are several debuggers that Emacs can use.

For GDB/MI  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html

```
SPC SPC gdb
Run gdb (like this): gdb -i=mi foo
```

For RealGUD, install RealGUD from https://github.com/realgud/realgud

```
SPC SPC load-library ENT realgud ENT
SPC SPC realgud:gdb
Run gdb (like this): gdb foo
```